# How can select a particular field of table stored in SQL server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i am working on asp.net mvc3. i am using database designed in sql server. i have added my database in App_Data using Ado.connection.

This is my table:

[image]

I want to access Code where ID=2

I am using this query:

```
ViewBag.pc = db.Product.Where(r => r.ID == p);
```

but this returns whole row. So what should i do to select particular column(here code). Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var code = db.Product.Where(r => r.ID == 2).Single().Code` should work.

If there could be more than one row (or none), you can use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var row = db.Product.Where(r => r.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
if(row != null)
{
     var code = row.Code;
}
```

If there can only be one(or none), you can replace `FirstOrDefault()` with `SingleOrDefault()` above.

Comment: That is fine as long as `ID` is unique. If it's not, use `FirstOrDefault` instead. +1 still

Comment: This will still fetch the whole row from the DB though. Doesn't matter too much in this case, but you can select the `Code` only by doing `db.Product.Where(r => r.ID == 2).Select(r => r.Code).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is assigning the `ViewBag.pc` variable with a `Product` object. This means that `ViewBag.pc` object will have properties for each column in the table.

So, to refer to the data stored in the `Code` column in your view, you would use something like this:

```
<%: ViewBag.pc.Code %>
```